# FragmentPagerAdapter not working

Tags: java, android, fragment

When I create my `FragmentPagerAdapter` and I define the number of pages as 3, page 1 will have content, page 2 will NOT have content, and page 3 will have content. If I change the number of pages to 4 or more, every page has content. Why is this? If I create 2 pages, there is NO content? What am I missing with this?

Here is my code:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        /*
         * Here we are going to return the correct type of fragment for each
         * of the pages
         */
        Log.d("Position", "Default Postion: " + position);
        return MainListFragment.init(position); 

    }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }
```

I realize that all my content is the same, and that is okay. The point here is that when I have 3 pages only 2 have content. If I have 4 or more pages, everything works as expected.

What is even more odd is that I have put outputs in the `onCreate` method of the `ListFragment`, which is what is displayed, and it actually creates all the `ListFragments` but it does not display them all.

EDIT:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_feed);

        RequestUserFeed feed = new RequestUserFeed();
        feed.execute(URL);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
public static class MainListFragment extends ListFragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */

        int fragNum;
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        private static MainListFragment init(int val) {
            MainListFragment mfl = new MainListFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("val", val);
            mfl.setArguments(args);

            return mfl;
        }

        public MainListFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Retrieving this instance's number from its arguments.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.d("Fragment", "Fragment Created for " + getArguments().getInt("val"));
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_fragment,
                    container, false);



            return rootView;
        }

         @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                SettingListAdapter settingAdapter = new SettingListAdapter(
                        getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        R.layout.setting_item_row, MainFeedActivity.mProfileList);
                ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                listView.setAdapter(settingAdapter);
            }


    }
```

In the current state I will only get a list view on one page. If I move this code:

```
SettingListAdapter settingAdapter = new SettingListAdapter(
                        getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        R.layout.setting_item_row, MainFeedActivity.mProfileList);
                ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                listView.setAdapter(settingAdapter);
```

to `onCreateView` I will get a different result. Setting the list adapter in `onCreateView` will populate more pages. Confusing I know, but figured it would be worth a mention.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have positions defined this way in switch in `getItem`. You have 3 items, so positions will be 0, 1, 2:

```
switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Log.d("Position", "Postion: " + position);
            return MainListFragment.init(position); 
        case 1:
            Log.d("Position", "Postion: " + position);
            return MainListFragment.init(position); 
        case 2:
            Log.d("Position", "Postion: " + position);
            return MainListFragment.init(position); 
        }
```

Comment: I understand that it's a 0 based system. 0 is page 1, 1 is page 2, and 2 is page 3... I get that, but it doesn't explain why the data isn't rendering when there are 3 pages. Also, since I have the `default` in the switch, any page that doesn't match will default to that.

Comment: In your original code you have positions 10 and 21. But position parameter will never have a value more than 2 if your `getCount()` returns 3.

Comment: That doesn't matter. I've done it the way you suggested and it doesn't work any differently. Besides, using your logic, page 1 should still work. It doesn't. That is the page I'm having trouble with.

Comment: How do you use `SectionsPagerAdapter`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I'm trying to help you and I'm trying to understand your code. One more question: what is `MainListFragment.init(...)`?

Comment: Hmm, puzzling. I'm comparing to my code but can't see where it's wrong yet. The only difference I can see is that I don't use a static method to create fragments, I do it straight in getItem. Shouldn't matter though...

Comment: It's fricking weird man. I suppose I could try using objects rather than static initializers...